# Query que altera a quantidade de itens no MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma *query* que altera a quantidade no MySQL (abaixo). Inicialmente essa *query* funciona perfeitamente, mas quando eu cadastro novos itens na tabela, alguns deles não alteram corretamente a quantidade, mas alguns continuam normais.

Por exemplo, nessa *query* eu atualizo a partir do ID da lente (que é o produto que uso nesse sistema):

```
ID:10 Quantidade: 10
ID:11 Quantidade: 20
```

Ai eu uso a *query*, no começo funciona normal (como eu disse lá em cima), mas depois *buga*, eu coloco pro ID:10 aumentar 5, ai ele vai pra 15 (normal), mas eu coloco pro ID:11 aumentar 10, em vez de ir pra 30 ele vai pra 23, ou 12, ou qualquer outro número.

```
<?php
include_once("db.php");
$idad = $_POST['idad'];
$qntad = $_POST['qntad'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM lentes ";
$query = $con->query($sql);
while($lentes = $query->fetch_array()){
    $idlente = $lentes["ID"];
    $qntlente = $lentes["quantidade"];
}
$altera = ($qntlente) + ($qntad);

$sql="UPDATE `lentes` SET `quantidade` = $altera WHERE `lentes`.`ID` = $idad";


   if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    print "<script>
    alert('Lente de ID $idad atualizada com sucesso! Saldo atual: $altera')
location.href='index.php'
</script>";
     {
    die(print "<script>
    alert('Ops! Lente fora de estoque! Saldo atual: $qntlente')
location.href='index.php'
</script>");
}   



?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *query* `SELECT * FROM lentes` retorna todas as lentes cadastradas. Não deveria existir uma cláusula `WHERE` para a lente específica (`$idad`)?

Comment: Nossa, não acredito que era tão besta kk, não pensei que era isso justamente pq alguns funcionavam normal, valeu ai :D